Reading as 'System.Object' is not supported for fields having DataType during adapter.Fill(dataTable) postgresSQL
I have my C# code upgraded from .NET 6 to .NET 8.
This code used to work fine in .NET 6:
using (var adapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(sql, context.Database.GetDbConnection() as NpgsqlConnection))
{
    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(dataTable);

    return dataTable;
}

After the code was upgraded to .NET 8, it throws the following error:

Reading as 'System.Object' is not supported for fields having DataType
Detailed exception is:
at Npgsql.Internal.AdoSerializerHelpers.g__ThrowReadingNotSupported|0_0(Type type, String displayName, Exception inner)
at Npgsql.Internal.AdoSerializerHelpers.GetTypeInfoForReading(Type type, PostgresType postgresType, PgSerializerOptions options)
at Npgsql.BackendMessages.FieldDescription.g__GetInfoSlow|50_0(Type type, ColumnInfo& lastColumnInfo)
at Npgsql.BackendMessages.FieldDescription.GetInfo(Type type, ColumnInfo& lastColumnInfo)
at Npgsql.BackendMessages.FieldDescription.get_ObjectOrDefaultInfo()
at Npgsql.BackendMessages.FieldDescription.get_FieldType()
at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.GetFieldType(Int32 ordinal)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.SchemaMapping.SetupSchemaWithoutKeyInfo(MissingMappingAction mappingAction, MissingSchemaAction schemaAction, Boolean gettingData, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object chapterValue)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.SchemaMapping..ctor(DataAdapter adapter, DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Boolean keyInfo, SchemaType schemaType, String sourceTableName, Boolean gettingData, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillMappingInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 schemaCount, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillMapping(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 schemaCount, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)

Any help is appreciated.

It's a little scary you'll provide an sql string without also checking for parameters.
